# Magento 2 - What is the purpose of the sequence_* tables?

Tags: magento2, database

What is the purpose of the sequence_* tables, e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sequence_* tables records the increment_id for corresponding entities like order/invoice/shipment.

For more details check https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/multi-sites/change-increment-id.html